# Upload image from web: Does not accept IDNs

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

It's all in the title, really. I entered a URL and had to edit `http://filedump.ýes.info/UbuntuPartitions.png` to `http://filedump.xn-es-zka.info/UbuntuPartitions.png`. It appears to be failing here too in the preview, which is odd as I know that IDNs have worked properly for me before in comments.

Answer (score 1):

We only support a restricted standard ASCII set in URLs.

Comment: http://filedump.ýes.info/UbuntuPartitions.png

Comment: So why does it work in comments?

Comment: Really, why does it work in comments? A little consistency would help.